Excel treats a date in format (dd-MMM-yy) differently if typed or pasted
This was discovered when opening a file in CSV format that has a column of dates in the format dd-MMM-yy (e.g 20-FEB-24). When opening this file in Excel (Excel 365 desktop) if the 2 year value is <30 the date string is converted to a DATE with year 20XX where XX is the 2 year value of the date string. If the 2 year value is >=30 then the string is converted to a Date with year 19XX.
I have already changed the Windows setting already so it doesn't appear that this affects the result.

I can replicate this by copying the text string "20-FEB-30", pasting it into a cell in Excel and pressing enter - resulting in a date 20/02/1930 and then in a new cell typing the string "20-FEB-30" and pressing return which results in a date of 20/02/2030.
Is there any setting in Excel that controls this 1930 date split/why pasted values are treated differently to typed values?

See this explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/two-digit-year-numbers
especially the note: This will modify the way Excel interprets dates only when they are typed into a cell. If you import or programmatically enter a date, the following 2029 rule is always in effect.

Consider this answer about why pasted values might be treated differently to typed values.

@MGonet - I had come across this happening when entering dates programmatically but hadnt experienced it when opening from CSVs or just plain pasting a value. I'm assuming therefore that there is no-way of overriding the 2029 rule?

I think so, no-way of overriding the 2029 rule.
